# How to replace the first three character on a string

Tags: php, regex

How to replace the first three special character in my string.?
This is the sample.

```
$string = "~~MASTER FOR OILCHEM; ETD - MID OF JUNE~~";
 echo preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $string);
```

The outout will be :

```
MASTERFOROILCHEMETDMIDOFJUNE
```

But I want the fist three special character to be replace. So the output will be :

```
MASTER FOR OILCHEM; ETD - MID OF JUNE~~
```

Comment: How about substring($string, 2);

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `regex` you can simply use `substr` like as

```
$string = "~~MASTER FOR OILCHEM; ETD - MID OF JUNE~~";
echo substr($string,2);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code searches for 0 up to 3 non word characters and replaces them with an empty string:

```
$string = "~~MASTER FOR OILCHEM; ETD - MID OF JUNE~~";
echo preg_replace("/^\W{0,3}/", "", $string);
```

The above PHP outputs the following:

```
MASTER FOR OILCHEM; ETD - MID OF JUNE~~
```

See https://3v4l.org/lFKXV for a live example.

And regarding Regular Expressions, you should try this great tool.
https://regex101.com/r/pD7vR7/1